# how to validate a field that must be false in laravel form request

Tags: laravel-6

I want to set ('is_color' = false) if ('is_variation' = true) in form request

```
        $rules  = [
            'is_color'                      =>  'nullable|boolean',
            'is_guarantee'                  =>  'nullable|boolean',
            'is_variation'                  =>  'nullable|boolean',
        ];
```

Comment: How is this related to validation? Validate your data, then apply the `if (variation == true) is_color = false;` logic afterwards

Comment: @kerbholz: I want the validation to be inside the  form request, not in the controller.
actually, if the user choose the is_variation and is_color v at the same time, i want it to display the error inside the form request, and before going to the controller

Comment: Do you only want one of 3 options to be allowed to be true? Or is only this a connection between `is_color` and `is_variation`?

Comment: have you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not related to the validation, What I found out is you want set `is_color` due to `is_variation`'s value, so you can validate just `is_variation` and set `is_color`.
But you can validate these parameter related to each other with make a method named `withValidator` in your form request. For more information you can see below link: 
[With Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362522/laravel-withvalidator-not-working-as-expected)

Or you can make custom rule validation :
[Custom Validation in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)